# Factoring constant parts of division into a unique constant

Tags: linear-algebra, factoring

I am writing a program for a slow micro controller. I have to calculate the equation below many times. The division and multiplication are very time consuming so I am looking to convert at least a part of the equation to a compile time constant. Can you please help me to figure out how to factor out the currently known constants? Here is the equation

In code:

```
((A / (var / B)) / C)
```

In math I beleive it should be:
$$\frac{\frac{A}{\frac{var}{B}}}{C}$$

So, the only variable element here is the **var** and every thing else is numerical constants.

Is it possible to factor **A**, **B** and  **C** as a constant **D** and at the end do something like:

**ANSWER = var * D**

Comment: I believe what you want is $\frac {AB}{C}\times \frac 1{\text {var}}$, so $D$ would be $\frac {AB}C$...though it's a division in the end, not a multiplication.

Comment: `for a slow micro controller` Are `A,B,C,var` integers or floating points? If the former (and if `/` means *integer* division), note that rearranging the formula could change the result, even if the two forms may be mathematically equivalent.

Comment: @dxiv A and C are integers, B is floating point. will it make difference? final answer should be integer (rounded float to integer)

Comment: @DEKKER That depends on the language e.g. in **C** all operations would be promoted to floating-point because of $B$, but $\frac{1}{var}$ would be integer division if $var$ were declared as an integer (and would therefore evaluate to $0$ unless $var=\pm1$).